# Filtering a relationship() in a single query with SQLAlchemy ORM?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got `urls` and `requests` tables, and I've defined a relationship like so:

```
class Request(Base):
    ...
    url_id = Column('url_id', Integer, ForeignKey(Url.id))
    requests = relationship(Url, backref='requests')
```

Which means I can ask `Url.requests` and get *all* of the requests that have ever been made for a given Url.  However, what I would like to do is get `requests` for a set of Urls that are limited to a specific date.

I can write this to get the result set that I want, but I don't know how to package this up neatly so I can iterate over my `Url` objects and get `.requests` for each one.  Ideally I would like to eagerload these Request objects as well.  Here's what I write to get the rows back that I want:

```
session.query(Url).join(Request).filter(Request.created >= start_date, Request.created < end_date)
```

If I dump the query it looks pretty reasonable, but when I iterate over the urls and ask each for `.requests` I get *all* of the requests back, instead of just the ones that passed my filter.  Is it possible to do this with the ORM?

Answer (score 1):

```
session.query(Url).join(Url.request).\
    options(contains_eager(Url.request)).\
    filter(Request.created >= start_date, Request.created < end_date)
```

Should work out for you. Check out the docs on joining for ideas of joining with eager loaded data.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/loading.html